# Nginx get the current ip

Tags: nginx

I'm writing a generic config script for a site and want to block all traffic to a certain url except the traffic from the server itself because I want to allow only SSH tunneled trafic to access that part of the site.

```
location /admin {
    allow SERVERIP; 
    deny all;
}
```

Has nginx a variable I can use for this so I don't have to add it manually for every server I use the config with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$server_addr

an address of the server which accepted a request

Computing a value of this variable usually requires one system call. To avoid a system call, the listen directives must specify addresses and use the bind parameter.
```

[Documented here.](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_server_addr)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an SSH tunnel, it's likely that your traffic to nginx will be coming from 127.0.0.1, so just allow that.

Comment: I thought so but for some reason I can't get the config working with localhost or the serverip.

Comment: Just tried localhost and it seems to work as you suggested unfortunately $server_addr is more or less what I asked for so I rewarded that answer although I'm sure using localhost is more effecient as it doesn't need the extra lookup.

Comment: Note that if you've got IPv6 enabled on the box that `localhost` will sometimes resolve (first) to `::1` which might cause issues for servers that are only listening on IPv4 (and why I explicitly suggested `127.0.0.1`)